# Higher overlay specs break movie15's \includemovie

Tags: beamer, overlays, movie15

If items preceding `\only<X>{\includemovie}` have overlay spec strictly higher than X, let's say Y > X, then the movie does not appear. It looks like it thinks the movie should appear on slide Y instead of X.

Minimal test case: https://www.overleaf.com/read/pxvrsdgjscbc

```latex
\documentclass[draft]{beamer}

% Yeah, it's obsolete, but media9 is even more so now that Flash is dead
\usepackage{movie15}

% Notes from movie15:
% 1. Options `autopause' and `autoresume' should be set, as this prevents the
%    movie from being rewound when passing from one overlay to the next.
%%%%% -> BTW I never got this to work, overlays always reset movies for me, tried in Okular and pympress.

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
  \frametitle{Cool video frame}

   Here is a cool movie coming up. 
   
   \visible<3->{That was a cool movie, eh?}
   
   % This wouldn't break it, but the overlay spec cannot be after the movie
%   \visible<2->{That was a cool movie, eh?}

  \only<2>{
    \centering
    \includemovie[url]{0.8\linewidth}{.45\linewidth}{coolmovie.mp4}}
    
  % This works, but limits us to only specify stuff after \includemovie 
%  \visible<3->{That was a cool movie, eh?}
  
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

What happens: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMAq7.png)

The expected result can be obtained **only** by placing `\visible<3->{That was a cool movie, eh?}` **after** `\includemovie` (uncommenting the last one). [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvK3m.png)

Cross-referencing issue opened on Beamer Github, as I believe this is a bug: https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/733